# WinXP - forced root filesystem check skipped during reboot

Tags: windows, windows-xp, reboot, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

The forced system drive (or root filesystem or in this case `c:`) filesystem check by HDD properties->tools->check now or by `chkdsk c: /f` is not executed at the next reboot. I'm aware I could check the filesystem by booting from another media, but that's not an option for telephone support. Any ideas why chkdsk might be skipped while enforced?

Comment: I can only assume the system drive isn't actually labeled as `C:`

Comment: sorry, root drive == system

Comment: I would simply modify the registry key that handles this.  There are dozens of questions on how to disable this scan from happening, just use the reverse procedure to enable it.